# Reference request: SLLN for correlated/exchangeable random variables

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-processes

Is there any strong law of large number for correlated but identically distributed random variables or exchangeable random variables?

A further question, what about random variables taking values in arbitrary Banach spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SLLN when the variables are not IID is often referred to as the Ergodic theorem, see Chapter 6 of Brieman's (1968) Probability text. Have a look at Linear Processes in Function Spaces by Bosq for SLLN's and ergodic theorems in Banach space.